# Converting DateTime string field to Unix/Epoch time in Logstash

Tags: logstash, cloudflare

I am ingesting logs from cloudflare and two fields are not able to parse (EdgeStartTimeStamp, EdgeEndTimeStamp)

```
"reason" =>"failed to parse field [EdgeEndTimeStamp] of type [long]", "caused by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"2020-07-2100:02:00z\""}
```

EdgeStartTimestamp -> Timestamp at which the edge received request from the client  int or string

I am looking to convert this to EdgeEndTimeStamp to epoch time. I have tried

```
    if ([EdgeStartTimestamp]) {
        date {
            match => ["EdgeStartTimestamp", "ISO8601"]
            target => "myDateObj"
        }
        ruby {
            code => "set.event('EdgeStartTimestamp', (event.get('myDateObj').to_f*1000).to_i)"
        }
    }
```